# What causes my new web server to delay its response?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, slow-connection

I'm migrating my servers from Rackspace over to Amazon.  Our servers are running mod_perl and the connect times are much longer on the Amazon server (oftentimes up to 1 second just to connect) with the same config.  Ten concurrent connection can be 100-500ms in connect time alone.

The actually processing times are very fast.  The perl script we're using for testing doesn't dip into a database.

Changing the size of the EC2 instance does not affect the connect time in any way.

I assume that means that something's up with the Apache config, but I don't know where to look.

Can anyone recommend where to look/troubleshoot?

Comment: Is the name lookup on into your apache config ?

Comment: Are you using mod_perl handlers, Registry, or CGI? MPM? Server/Clients configuration lines? It's normal for the first connection to take a while per server thread, unless you precompile your handlers in the startup script.

Comment: Pertinent lines:  HostnameLookups Off, LoadModule perl_module modules/mod_perl.so, ModPerl::Registry is off for testing, but will be needed in production.  MaxClients 150, StartServers 5, MinSpareServers 5, MaxSpareServers 10, MaxRequestsPerChild 0, KeepAlive off.